# If I use the auto scaling features of Azure Web Sites do I need to set a specific machine key?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, machinekey

If you use auto scaling with Azure Web Sites do you need to set the machine key so encrypted authentication tokens can be shared between machines?

There is a question here which appears to [be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085726/with-azure-auto-scaling-do-i-need-to-specify-a-machinekey-in-web-config)  as the one I am asking. However that question refers to Azure Web Roles. I am asking about Azure Web Sites.

Comment: You actually can't set the machine key on Azure Websites, it's one of the protected environment settings.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with setting the machine key? I am having this problem for 3 days that it always gives me an error: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you don't need to. Azure Website will set the same machine key for all your instances when they are running on 2 (or 10) different VMs.

If you want a quick and dirty way to verify this, have the following bit of code in your `Application_Start()` basically this writes the machine key into a file called `%WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID%` this is a unique environment variable per instance. Scale to 2 machines, turn on `Always On` setting and within a minute 2 files should be written in your `D:\home\site\wwwroot` folder that have a long guid for names (the instance id for the 2 machines) and they will contain the same key.

*[code credit goes to this](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey)*

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var section = (MachineKeySection)
        ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");

    BindingFlags flags =
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.GetProperty;

    Func<string, byte[]> propertyReader = name => (byte[])section
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(name, flags)
        .GetValue(section, null);

     using (
        var writer =
            new StreamWriter(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOME%\site\wwwroot\%WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID%.log")))
    {
        var key = ConvertToHex(
            propertyReader("DecryptionKeyInternal"));
        writer.WriteLine("DecryptKey: {0}", key);

        var iv = ConvertToHex(
            propertyReader("ValidationKeyInternal"));
        writer.WriteLine("ValidationKey: {0}", iv);
    }

}

private string ConvertToHex(byte[] binary)
{
    return binary.Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (acc, c) => acc.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", c),
        acc => acc.ToString());
}
```